# What does "return 0x8000 0000;" mean?

Tags: c

I saw the following code(part of a function):

```
if (end == start)
{
    *max = *min = *start;
    return 0x80000000;
}
```

I dont understand why it returns 0x80000000,which is `2^31`,and it is out of int's range and has type `unsigned int`

And what is it equal to ?

---

Complete code:

```
int MaxDiffCore(int* start, int* end, int* max, int* min)
{
if (end == start)
{
    *max = *min = *start;
    return 0x80000000;
}
int* middle = start + (end - start) / 2; 
int maxLeft, minLeft; 
int leftDiff = MaxDiffCore(start, middle, &maxLeft, &minLeft); 
int maxRight, minRight; 
int rightDiff = MaxDiffCore(middle + 1, end, &maxRight, &minRight); 
int crossDiff = maxLeft - minRight;
*max = (maxLeft > maxRight) ? maxLeft : maxRight;
*min = (minLeft < minRight) ? minLeft : minRight; 
int maxDiff = (leftDiff > rightDiff) ? leftDiff : rightDiff;
maxDiff = (maxDiff > crossDiff) ? maxDiff : crossDiff; 
return maxDiff;
}
```

Comment: perfectly legal 32 bit unsigned int...

Comment: How many bits do you think an `int` has on your system?  32 is quite common.

Comment: Of course I know it it is unsigned int

Comment: Check this for ranges of various data types:: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/s3f49ktz.aspx

Comment: On a system with 32-bit integers, `0x80000000` is the smallest possible integer, i.e., the most negative number that can be represented.  It is -(2**31), which is representable in a 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: Also, what some code returns is purely based on the coder's logic. I can return 0 or 1 or 0xF, and only I will know, what do these return values mean to me.

Comment: Bad code. Lots of it around.

Comment: This return 'value' lacks portability. It would behave differently on 32bit and 64bit machines. Please check my answer for details.

Comment: @Tom Karzes Disagree with "0x80000000 is the smallest possible integer,"  OP is right with "which is 2^31,and it is out of int's range and has type unsigned int"  As 32-bit integers, `0x80000000` is a positive  hexadecimal constant with type `unsigned`. It is not the the smallest possible integer, but 1 greater than `INT_MAX`.  How that number [converts (or not)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36147189/2410359) to an `int` is the issue.

Comment: FWIW: The code can easily invoke `int` overflow (UB) with `int crossDiff = maxLeft - minRight;`

Comment: @chux In this context, it's being used as a signed `int` value (it's being returned from a signed `int` function), so what I said was clearly the intent.  Whether or not it's portable is a different issue.  The question was why the code was written that way, and I answered it:  The intent was to return `MIN_INT`.  Clearly this will only do that on a system with 32-bit two's complement integers, and in fact it should have used `MIN_INT` instead.  But that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 2):

0x80000000 is not out of `int`'s range.  An `int` is platform dependent, and there are platforms where `int` is 32 bits wide.  This number is 32 bits wide, so it will do a "straight bit assignment" to the `int`.

Yes, the decimal representation of this number is `2^31` but that's only if you interpret the bits as `unsigned`, which in the case of bits, makes little sense.  You really need to look at the L-value to know what it is going to be handled as, and that's a signed `int`/

Now, assuming this is a 32 bit platform, this is a fancy way to write MIN_INT, and by fancy, I mean non-portable and requiring a lot of assumptions that aren't constant, and finally confusing to those who don't want to do the binary math.  It assumes 2's complement math and opts to set the bits directly.

Basically, with 2's complement numbers, zero is still

```
0x00000000
```

but to get `-1 + 1 = 0` you have to get something to add to 1 yeilding 0

```
  0x????????
+ 0x00000001
= 0x00000000
```

So you choose

```
  0x11111111
+ 0x00000001
= 0x00000000
```

relying on the carrying 1's to eventually walk off the end.  You can then deduce that 1 lower is -2 and so on; up to a point `-2 = 0x11111110` and so on.  Basically since the first bit determines the "sign" of the number, the "biggest" negative number you could have would be `0x1000000` and if you tried to subtract 1 from that, you would carry from the "negative" sign bit yielding the largest positive number. `0x01111111`.

Comment: It is kind of outside `int` range, assuming 32-bit `int`. C is just nice enough to implicitly cast it for us from `unsigned int` to `int`, something that some other languages would refuse to do. You would need 64-bit `int` to say unambiguously that it is in `int` range and not feel a bit queasy about it. +1 for "fancy way to write MIN_INT" though.

Comment: @Amadan It is a straight hex assignment, there's no such thing as a negative sign on a hexadecimal number.  As long as the bit length is the same, it's not outside the range of an `int` it is just the __bit representation__ of a different `int` than most people would think of initially.

Comment: @Edwin Buck thanks

Comment: `0x80000000` **is** out of `int`'s (32-bit int) range.  With 32-bit `int/unsigned`, `0x80000000` is an `unsigned` with a value 1 greater than `INT_MAX`.  The fact it converts nicely in OP's case to `INT_MIN` is  [implementation defined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36147189/2410359).  Code would have been better off with [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147034/what-does-return-0x8000-0000-mean#comment59932041_36147119).

Comment: @chux My comment was in response to a question that's now long gone.  Basically this routine returns a "magic number" and worse, encoded that "magic number" in a confusing way.  I wouldn't relish working on such code, but odd things like this exist, more often than not.  I'm deleting the comment above because without the context it's just odd.  I'm just trying to point out that there are few platforms with 31 bit `int`s.  The bits fit into the storage, they just don't __represent__ a positive number.

Comment: Agree about difficulties with code.  It does not appear to be returning a magic number, as much as the minimum number possible and is used in subsequent calculations.  IAC, I think the function is broken in other ways too.

Answer (score 1):

If the constant has type `unsigned int` on your platform and the function is declared as returning `int`, then the `unsigned int` value will get implicitly converted to type `int`. If the original value does not fit into `int` range, the result of this conversion is implementation-defined (or it might raise a signal).

> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> **3** Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is
>   implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Consult your compiler documentation to see what will happen in this case. Apparently the authors of the code came to conclusion that the implementation does exactly what they wanted it to do. For example, a natural thing to expect is for some implementation to "reinterpret" this bit pattern as a signed integer value with the highest-order bit becoming the sign bit. It will convert `0x80000000` into `INT_MIN` value on a 2's-complement platform with 32-bit `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong practice and the return value should be corrected.
The code is returning binary `10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000` and

**On machines where sizeof(int) = 4byte :**

- In your case, function return type `int` is treating it as binary `10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000` = integer `-2147483648` (negative value).
- If function return type would have been `unsigned int`, it would have treated `0x80000000` as binary `10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000` = integer `2147483648`

**On machines where sizeof(int) = 2byte :**

- The result would be implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal would be raised [[see other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36147189/5737548)].

Comment: Thanks and I've updated my question, I don't understand why it returns 0x8000 0000,why not return 0 or any other number

Comment: updated my answer. :) though it needs some formatting.

Comment: But if it is signed , it is -2*31,isn't it? according to two's complement

Comment: Why "signed zero"? In the exotic signed magnitude representation it would be treated as signed zero. But not in 2's complement or 1's complement.

Comment: @dongxingshi: Apologies. It was a mistake. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: @AnT: Thank you for figuring that out. :) I've updated my answer.

Comment: "(assuming your machine as 64bit machine)" is not needed and confuses the issue as on a 64-bit machine, the complier could use a 64-bit `int` - recommend deletion.  The "On machines where sizeof(int) = 4byte" is sufficient.

Comment: "This would result in an integer overflow" is incorrect.  See [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36147189/2410359)

Comment: Learnt something new and corrected my answer. :) Thanks a ton @chux.